# ParseException error

Tags: java, oracle, jdatechooser

I am actually trying to populate a jdatechooser with the date fetched from oracle database. The date is stored as 11-JUL-1995 in the database. But when I try to fetch it from the database using the following code, the error is shown as:-
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "11-Jul-1995". Please tell me what am i doing wrong??
Code:-

```
String dob=rs1.getString("DOB");
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mmm-yyyy").parse(dob);  //SETTING DATE FROM DATABASE INTO DATECHOOSER
dc.setDate(date);
```

Here, dc is the jdatechooser and String dob is the date retrieved from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

should be `dd-MMM-yyyy`. `m` refers to minutes. Always refer to [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for more information

`Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy").parse(dob);`

Comment: Thank you very much, changing to MMM solved my problem.